# frama-c [kernel] user error: skipping file "selection.c" that has errors

Tags: frama-c

I am a new user of Frama-c. I just installed Neon-20140301 and why 2.34
on my Fedora 14 system with Ocaml compiler 4.01.0.

Under no-GUI mode, install was successful.

However, when I tried to run some examples from why2.34, I got several errors like the following:
It seems that there is a compatibility problem.

---

```
[user  /data/Down/why-2.34/examples-c/sorting]$ frama-c -jessie selection.c
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  -dD selection.c"
 selection.c:4:[kernel] user error: unexpected token ''
[kernel] user error: skipping file "selection.c" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
[user  /data/Down/why-2.34/examples-c/sorting]$ cat selection.c

 /* Selection sort */

 //@ type intmset

  //@ logic intmset mset(int t[],int i,int j) reads t[..]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked in duplicate in the mailing list and [answered](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2014-September/004556.html) by Claude Marché:

> The examples in directory examples-c/ of why are old examples using 
>   Caduceus syntax, a kind of predecessor of Frama-C.
>
> Up-to-date examples can be found in directory tests/c/ instead, and
>   also  in several other places, e.g. "ACSL by examples", etc.